# MaraDNS- Unable to forward DNS queries

Tags: networking, dns, iptables

I tried forwarding DNS queries to Google DNS but it is not working. Below is the content of my `/etc/mararc` file:

```
csv2 = {}

csv2["example.net."] = "db.example.net"
csv2["google.com."] = "db.google.com"

ipv4_bind_addresses = "127.0.0.1"
chroot_dir = "/etc/maradns"
recursive_acl = "127.0.0.1/16"
upstream_servers = {}
upstream_servers["."] = "8.8.8.8"
```

When I check for `gmail.com` DNS resolution through `nslookup`, I get:

```
> server 127.0.0.1
Default server: 127.0.0.1
Address: 127.0.0.1#53
> gmail.com
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

I have allowed outgoing DNS queries from `iptables` as:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Below solution worked for me. I have to use MaraDNS Deadwood for forwarding the DNS queries. Below is the content of `/etc/dwood3rc`:

```
bind_address="127.0.0.1" # IP we bind to

chroot_dir = "/etc/maradns" # Directory we run program from (not used in Win32)

recursive_acl = "127.0.0.1/16"
upstream_servers = {}
upstream_servers["."] = "8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4"

maxprocs = 8 # Maximum number of pending requests
handle_overload = 1 # Send SERVER FAIL when overloaded

maradns_uid = 99 # UID Deadwood runs as
maradns_gid = 99 # GID Deadwood runs as

maximum_cache_elements = 60000

cache_file = "dw_cache"

resurrections = 1
```

Here is the content of my `/etc/mararc` file:

```
csv2 = {}

csv2["example.net."] = "db.example.net" #Sample Record, just to try
csv2["google.com."] = "db.google.com" #Sample Record, just to try

ipv4_bind_addresses = "127.0.0.1"
chroot_dir = "/etc/maradns"
```

And then restart both the services, as:

```
service maradns.deadwood restart

service maradns restart
```

Hope it helps someone!